# VSCode GoToDefinition with DeclarationsMap

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I'm attempting to get the DeclarationsMap working within VSCode for a multi-module project so that the action "Go to Definition (F12)" will take me to the `.ts` file rather than the `.d.ts`.  Typescript added the declarations map via this PR https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22658

Yet when I press F12 it always takes me to the types definitions file and I have no idea how to fix this.  Any help would be appreciated.  Below you can find some rough outlines of how I setup my project.

```
MyProject
    module-1
      dependencies: module-2
    module-2
```

**Module-2 TsConfig**

```
...
outDir: "./dist"
rootDir: "./src"
declaration: true
declarationMap: true
sourceRoot: "https://github/.../MyProject/module-2/src"
...
```

**Module-2 package.json**

```
...
main: dist/index.js,
typings: dist/index.d.ts,
files: [ dist/ ]
...
```

The types (`index.d.ts`) files generated look like this:

```
export declare function myFunc(): void;
//# sourceMappingURL=index.d.ts.map
```

The map (`index.d.ts.map`) files look like this:

```
index.d.ts.map > {
  "version":3,
  "file":"index.d.ts",
  "sourceRoot":"https://github.com/.../MyProject/module-2/src/",
  "sources":["index.ts"]...}
```